# how can I set a default value on a jquery ui multiselect

Tags: jquery-ui

I am creating a collection_select in rails like this

```
<%= collection_select(:company, :business_type_id, @business_type, :id, :name, {:prompt => true},:id=>"companyType") %>
```

then with Jquery, I am turning it in the multiselect widget:

```
$("#companyType").multiselect({
  multiple: false,
  noneSelectedText: "Type",
  selectedList: 1
});
```

I would like to set a default value to it... any ideas on how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the default option using the Rails view helper. This is what i gather from the documentation of the [widget](http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/demos/#preselected)

```
<%= collection_select(:company, :business_type_id, @business_type, :id, :name, {:prompt => true},:id=>"companyType", :selected => @business_type.id) %>
```